# error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Tags: javascript

estoy programando un bot para discord y me pasa este error ( SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' ) al activar el cmd

este es mi codigo:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Estoy listo!");
 });
 
 client.on("message", (message) => {
   if(message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
     message.channel.send("pong!");
   }
 });
 client.login("token");
```

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código te lo muestra? Porque en el que has puesto no está el `??=`

Comment: Si es que estás con Node, ¿qué versión de Node estás utilizando? ¿Y la versión de discord.js?